# Using Past Simple in a past-subjunctive if-clause

Tags: subjunctives

When I refer to the past and use subjunctive-mood if-clause, do I have to use Past Perfect or using Past Simple is also fine?

For example, should it be like:

> Do you remember what happened when I first met that singer 20 years ago?
>   **If I hadn't known** anything about that singer, I would have definitely
>   considered him to be а mediocre.

or it can be like:

> Do you remember what happened when I first met that singer 20 years ago?
>   **If I didn't know** anything about that singer, I would have definitely
>   considered him to be а mediocre.

?

Answer (score 1):

Past Perfect should be used in this case, therefore " If I hadn't known..."
"Hadn't I known..." (inversion of subject and auxilliary) is also an option.